# Regex for finding all text urls but not in images src

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm replacing all text urls on page into clickable.

When i do this it also replaces links in 'src' attribute
of images (which is not desired)

My regex is this

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?
```

I tried negative search with

```
(?!src\=\")[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?
```

but it dosn't match a thing.

How should i precede my regex?

Comment: is javascript your only option..can't you do this with other server side languages

Comment: @Anirudh I made it as you suggested- server side.

Comment: Is the Question answered/closed?

Comment: @winner_joiner basically i made what Anirudh suggested. If you have solution for JS, you can post it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this...

```
(?:(href="))([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?)(?:([^>]*>[^<]*</a>))
```

I added non-capturing groups to the beginning and end to verify that it's an anchor href.  I tested it with this page's source at http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the question, but my interpretation is that you want to replace the value of *href* attribute in *A* elements.

This regex will find A elements that have an href attribute.  The value will be in the first capture group.

```
(?:<a[^>]*?href\s*=\s*")([^"]*)(?:")
```

Here is a version capturing all three parts of the match and using a replace function

```
myHtml.replace(/(<a[^>]*?href\s*=\s*")([^"]*)(")/gi, function(match, $1, $2, $3) {
    return $1 + "javascript.void(functionName('" + $2 + "'))" + $3;
});
```

if myHtml contained something like the following:

```
<a target="new" title="test" href="http://url.com">
```

it would get converted into this:

```
<a target="new" title="test" href="javascript.void(functionName('http://url.com'))">
```

You also mentioned clickable.

```
myHtml.replace(/(<a[^>]*?)(href\s*=\s*"([^"]*)")/gi, function(match, $1, $2, $3) {
    return $1 + "onclick=\"functionName('" + $3 + "')\"";
});
```

results in:

```
<a target="new" onclick="functionName('http://url.com')">
```

Btw, I tested this with my own regex tool:  http://rey.gimenez.biz